# Select values before commit() with transaction

Tags: c#, sql

Would it be possible to select some values from the rows I'm updating in my transaction, before committing the transaction?

Basically I need 1 table row to contain a specific value, and I'm using a transaction to rollback the table changes, if it sees that there is no row containing this value, at the end of my transaction.

Edit: I'm using C#'s `SqlTransaction`

Pseudo-code:

- Open database connection
- Start transaction
- Loop checkboxes

  - if checked

    - update table row `row_name`
- Loop end
- check table

  - if `row_name` doesn't contain `x` value

    - Do roll back
  - if `row_name` contains `x` value

    - Do commit
- End transaction

Comment: add some code to understand your problem better

Comment: Yes. In what ever session you update.. the updated info is available even without commit!

Comment: From where does x come?